# terminate a thread in C++ along with any process(es) it has spawned

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, kill, pid

I'm writing a fuzzer in C++ on linux.  It spawns multiple threads and has a timeout function if the thread hangs for whatever reason.  I cannot figure out the correct way to kill the thread off after it's timer runs out.  What I am doing now is something along the lines of:

```
`
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

#define READ   0
#define WRITE  1



void reaper (int c_pid, int t_timeout) {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(t_timeout));
  kill (c_pid, 9);
}


FILE * popen2 (std::string command, std::string type, int & pid, std::string low_lvl_user) {
  pid_t child_pid;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  if((child_pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (child_pid == 0) {  // child begins
    if (type == "r") {
      close(fd[READ]);    //Close the READ
      dup2(fd[WRITE], 1); //Redirect stdout to pipe
    }
    else {
      close(fd[WRITE]);    //Close the WRITE
      dup2(fd[READ], 0);   //Redirect stdin to pipe
    }
    if (getuid() == 0) {
      execl("/bin/su", "su", "-c", "/bin/sh", "-c", command.c_str(), low_lvl_user.c_str(), NULL);  // fixes not being able to reap suid 0 processes
    }
    else {
      execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL); // runs it all
    }
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
    if (type == "r") {
      close(fd[WRITE]); //Close the WRITE
    }
    else {
      close(fd[READ]); //Close the READ
    }
  }
  pid = child_pid;
  if (type == "r") {
    return fdopen(fd[READ], "r");
  }
  return fdopen(fd[WRITE], "w");
}


int pclose2(FILE * fp, pid_t pid) // close it so we don't fuck outselves
{
  int stat;
  fclose(fp);
  while (waitpid(pid, &stat, 0) == -1) {
    if (errno != EINTR) {
      stat = -1;
      break;
    }
  }
  return stat;
}


int spawn_ch (std::string out_str) {
  std::string low_lvl_user = "nobody";
  int t_timeout = 500;
      int pid;  // initializes child
      FILE * fp = popen2(out_str, "r", pid, low_lvl_user); // opens child process fork
      char command_out[4096] = {0};
      std::stringstream output;
      std::thread reaper_thread(reaper, pid, t_timeout);  // takes care of killing it off if it takes too long
      reaper_thread.join();
      while (read(fileno(fp), command_out, sizeof(command_out)-1) != 0) {
        output << std::string(command_out);
        memset(&command_out, 0, sizeof(command_out));
      }
      pclose2(fp, pid);
      std::string token;
}


int main () {
  std::string command = "HOME=AAAAAAAAA MAIL=AA  /usr/sbin/exim4 -Ac AAAAAA -G   -MCP,9,-Mar  -Mf  -Mset b -S 999999  -X,,-bF 999 -bdf  -bpc  -bpr   -bpru,,-bt   -exim4,AAA, -f,AAAAAAAAA,-oA   -oMa,5Mu^i, -oMaa,, -oMas,,-oMs  -oX isotanr -odb  -oee   -oem,999, -oo,99999999 -r 999999999 -t  -ti 999999";
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  int num_threads = 2;
  for (int cur_thread=1; cur_thread <= num_threads; ++cur_thread) threads.push_back(std::thread(spawn_ch, command));  // Thrift Shop
  for (auto& all_thread : threads) all_thread.join();  // is that your grandma's coat?
  exit(0);
}
```

But as the processes are spawned as suid 101 in this example (or 0, or whatever else), the kill function can be run as root to reap the processes it spawned... which would work, except exim4 apparently tries to spawn multiple processes, and when one dies the others don't.  Is there a way to let the program know what processes were spawned to kill them, or preferably, a way to just terminate the entire thread that spawned them (which I think should work, as if you ctrl+c my program it will kill off what it spawned)?

The whole codebase is on [github](https://github.com/oxagast/peachfuzz/blob/master/peachfuzz.cpp).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about keeping a list of PIDs upon fork and remove them upon done, so you have a list of PIDs to walk for the reaper function.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::thread` class provides no means to arbitrary terminate an active execution thread. This functionality is not implemented in the current C++ standard.

The sample code you posted is pretty much the only thing that can be done using purely the functionality in the C++ and C libraries.

The POSIX thread API is an alternative option. It does provide the means to terminate an active thread; however that comes with many important caveats, and it's very difficult to avoid undefined behavior, when terminating an execution thread using `pthread_cancel()`, since this will not properly unwind the terminated thread's stack, and invoke all the needed destructors; furthermore the executing thread must reach a cancellation point, in order for `pthread_cancel()` to take effect.

Additionally, if the executing thread execs another process, the new process is going to replace the thread's entire process, not just the executing thread's context. If this was your intent all along, trying to cancel the thread won't do much good anyway, and you pretty much have to do what you are already doing.